# UITextInputMode names?

Tags: ios, uitextinput

I know I can get the language codes for the UIInputModes via the primaryLanguage property

```
NSArray *inputModes = [UITextInputMode activeInputModes];

for (UITextInputMode *current in inputModes)
{
    NSString *primaryLanguage = current.primaryLanguage;
    NSLog(@"Current text input is: %@", primaryLanguage);

}
```

but how can I get the actual **names** of the Input Modes?  In other words, there could be multiple keyboards with "en-US" as the primary language... how do I determine which one is mine?

Thanks.